# Evaluate a double integral over a bounded region

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

I have the double integral $$\iint (x^4+y^2)dxdy$$ for the bounded region $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$

Is this simple as integrating with respect to x, followed by y with $x^3$ and $x^2$ as limits?

So  i would have $$\int \frac{1}{5}x^5 + xy^2  dy=[\frac{1}{5}x^5y+\frac{1}{3}xy^3]$$

Then adding in the limits we get $$(\frac{1}{5}x^8+\frac{1}{3}x^{10})-(\frac{1}{5}x^7+\frac{1}{3}x^{7})$$

Is this the correct? Many thanks

Comment: Should you not also have limits for integrating over $x$?

Comment: How would I find these limits? and why cant it just be an indefinite integration?

Comment: Read Taylor Teds answer below. It might also help to understand what you are doing when you double integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are integrating in order $dydx$, your $y$ limits are from $x^{3}$ to $x^{2}$ and x limits are from 0 to 1 (these are points of intersection of two curves)

When integrating w.r.t order $dxdy$, you will have limits for $x=y^{1/3}$(since region is in first quadrant we take positive sign) to $x=y^{1/2}$ and $y$ limits are from $0$ to $1$

Comment: Okay, so when I have integrated with respect to x, do i then sub in the limits, compute the answer and then integrate this with respect to y?

Comment: @LaurenBathers Edited answer,hope that helps!

Comment: Hey im slightly confused. So if the order is $dxdy$ and they have given me the region $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$, how do you get the x limits?

Comment: @LaurenBathers Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izTQjFteFKs&list=PLGqzsq0erqU7h6_bpE-CgJp4iX5aRju28&index=8